# Нужно ускорить работу программы по вычислению счастливого билета

Tags: python, c++

Как известно, в автобусах пассажирам выдают билеты с уникальным номером. Счастливым будем называть такие билеты, в которых сумма цифр, стоящих на четных позициях в номере, равна сумме цифр, стоящих на нечетных позициях. Известно также, что билеты выдаются подряд в порядке возрастания номеров. Василию выдали билет. Взглянув на его номер, он решил вычислить минимальный номер счастливого билета, номер которого больше номер его билета. Помогите Василию.

Технические условия. Программа читает с клавиатуры единственное число - номер билета Василия, который содержит не более 100 десятичных цифр. Программа выводит на экран минимальный номер счастливого билета, больше номер билета Василия.
Примеры:  123123 - 123134,
99 - 110.
Я сделал программу которая вычислят это число но она пролетает по таймлимитам. Моя идея в том чтобы записывать числа в массив и работать уже с ним а то 10^100 чисел это слишком много. Помогите мне это реализовать, пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
n = int(input())
n += 1

list_ = list(str(n))
even = []
odd = []
SUM_even = 0
SUM_odd = 0

for i in range(len(list_)):
    if i%2 == 0:
        even.append(i)
        SUM_even += int(list_[i])
    else:
        odd.append(i)
        SUM_odd += int(list_[i])

while SUM_odd != SUM_even:
    n += 1
    list_ = list(str(n))
    SUM_even, SUM_odd = 0, 0
    for i in range(len(list_)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            SUM_even += int(list_[i])
        else:
            SUM_odd += int(list_[i])
print(n)
```

Comment: А Вы можете назвать на каких числах (на каком вводе) выводится данная ошибка?

Comment: Ну а зачем вам работать с *числами*, если вполне можно сделать все прямо со строками?

Comment: во первых переписать на плюсы, работать будет быстрее, во вторых вы считали счастливый билет плохо, проще это делать из числа и остатками от деления, просто рассчитывая сумму, потом мы сможем узнать  разницу , а после этого легко обработать следующий счастливый билет

Comment: Есть алгоритм, работающий за время, пропорциональное количеству цифр в числе.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если просто убрать из вашего кода всё лишнее, он уже будет работать где-то в 2 раза быстрее. Возможно, этого уже хватит. Можно и дальше оптимизировать при желании, но там нужно будет алгоритмически что-то придумывать, я то просто ваш код от лишних преобразований почистил:

```
n = int(input())

while True:
    n += 1
    s = str(n)
    SUM_even = sum(map(int, s[::2]))
    SUM_odd = sum(map(int, s[1::2]))
    if SUM_even == SUM_odd:
        break

print(n)
```

Comment: Но интересно решить задачу без последовательного перебора кандидатов.

Answer (score 4):

Можно ускорить на порядок, если перебирать не все числа, а только кратные 11. Ведь равенство сумм чётных и нечетных цифр числа - это частный случай делимости на 11.

```
def is_lucky(num):
    s = str(num)
    return sum(map(int, s[::2])) == sum(map(int, s[1::2]))

n = int(input())
n = (n // 11 + 1) * 11
while not is_lucky(n):
    n += 11
    
print(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение за время пропорциональное длине числа и без длинной арифметики.

Для любого числа определим ошибку - отклонение его от счастливого: из суммы цифр на чётных местах вычтем сумму цифр на нечётных (места считаем с нуля с младших разрядов):

> ```
> 76543210      76543210
>
>                0 0 2 4  ->   6
> 90901234  ->                    -> -16
>               9 9 1 3   ->  22
> ```

Если ошибка нулевая, число счастливое.

Можно ли число с известными старшими разрядами дописать до счастливого? Например `90912???`. Ошибка для известных цифр равна `-19`. Что исправить ситуацию на нечётных местах оставим нули, на чётных девятки: `90912909` с ошибкой `-1`. А для числа `9091????` c ошибкой `-17` та же схема даст `90910909` c ошибкой `1`. Это даже больше чем нужно - перескочили через ноль. Если одну из новых девяток уменьшить до восьми получим точный ноль.

Общая идея: если добавлением нулей и девяток можно получить нулевую ошибку или изменить её знак, число можно дописать до счастливого.

Пусть известно что старшие разряды можно достроить до счастливого числа. Как это сделать так чтобы получилось минимальное счастливое число? Перебираем неизвестные разряды от старших к младшим. Цифры внутри разряда перебираем от нуля до девяти. Для каждой добавленой цифры проверяем "счастливость". Если получилось переходим к следующему разряду.

> ```
> 9091???? - известно что это число счастливое
>
>     3
> 90910??? - ошибка -17, число можно достроить до 90910909 (ошибка 1)
>
>      2
> 909100?? - ошибка -17, достроить нельзя
> 909101?? - ошибка -16, достроить нельзя
> ...
> 909107?? - ошибка -10, достроить нельзя
> 909108?? - ошибка  -9, число можно достроить до 90910809 (ошибка 0)
>
>       1
> 9091080? - ошибка  -9, число можно достроить до 90910809 (ошибка 0)
>
>        0
> 90910800 - ошибка  -9, достроить нельзя
> 90910801 - ошибка  -8, достроить нельзя
> ...
> 90910808 - ошибка  -1, достроить нельзя
> 90910809 - ошибка   0, разряды кончились, счастливое число построено
> ```

Как определить сколько разрядов стереть из исходного числа? Разряды перебираем справа налево, цифры в разряде - от меньших к девятке. Начинаем с цифры на единицу большей чем была в числе:

> ```
> 90912468 - исходное число
>
>        0   (d[0] = 8, проверяем значение 9) 
> 90912469 - ошибка -12, достроить нельзя
>
>       1    (d[1] = 6, проверяем диапазон [7, 9])
> 9091247? - ошибка -22, достроить нельзя
> 9091248? - ошибка -23, достроить нельзя
> 9091249? - ошибка -24, достроить нельзя
>
>      2     (d[2] = 4, проверяем диапазон [5, 9])
> 909125?? - ошибка -14, достроить нельзя
> ...
> 909129?? - ошибка -10, достроить нельзя
>
>     3      (d[3] = 2, проверяем диапазон [3, 9])
> 90913??? - ошибка -20, достроить нельзя
> ...
> 90919??? - ошибка -26, достроить нельзя
>
>    4       (d[4] = 1, проверяем диапазон [2, 9])
> 9092???? - ошибка -16, число можно достроить до 90920909 (ошибка 2)
> ```

Найдено наименьшее число, которое можно достроить до счастливого.

В программе числа хранятся в виде массивов цифр от младших разрядов к старшим - так проще обрабатывать. Вместе с числом хранится и обновляется его ошибка. Программа стирает младшие цифры пока не найдёт набор счастливых старших разрядов. Затем к ним добавляются новые младшие. На обоих этапах отыскиваются наменьшие возможные числа (но большие исходного числа). Сложность пропорциональна числу цифр в числе.

```
def next_lucky(s):
    number = list(map(int, reversed(s)))
    error = sum(number[::2]) - sum(number[1::2])

    def edit_number(i, inc):
        nonlocal error
        number[i] += inc
        error += inc if i % 2 == 0 else -inc

    def is_lucky(k):
        k_even = (k + 1) // 2
        k_odd = k - k_even
        return -9 * k_even <= error <= 9 * k_odd

    def lucky_prefix():
        for i in range(len(number)):
            for _ in range(number[i] + 1, 10):
                edit_number(i, 1) # number[i] += 1
                if is_lucky(i):
                    return i
            edit_number(i, -number[i]) # number[i] = 0
        i = len(number)
        number.append(0)
        edit_number(i, 1) # number[i] = 1
        return i

    def finish_lucky(k):
        for i in reversed(range(k)):
            for _ in range(10):
                if is_lucky(i):
                    break
                edit_number(i, 1) # number[i] += 1
        return ''.join(map(str, reversed(number)))

    return finish_lucky(lucky_prefix())


print(next_lucky(input()))
```

> ```
> $ echo 123123 | py next-lucky-ticket.py 
> 123134
>
> $ echo 99 | py next-lucky-ticket.py 
> 110
> ```